# Resizing Quad Frame Video from Cap

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I have this block of code that was suggested to me and I am trying to modify it using the Cap set for width and height to adjust the overall size of the quad display however every other run it throws this ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (240,320) into shape (480,640). Of course the numbers change depending on how I modify the size values in the set. My overall goal is to plug the quad frame into a tkinter gui I have that is right now showing single channels just fine. Currently my gui displays a 640x480 channel and I want to display the quad into that same size frame. Here is the current code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

red = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')
green = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')
blue = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, int(640 *.5))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, int(480 *.5))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)

    red[..., 0], red[..., 1], red[..., 2] = r, r, r
    green[..., 0], green[..., 1], green[..., 2] = g, g, g
    blue[..., 0], blue[..., 1], blue[..., 2] = b, b, b

    final = cv2.vconcat((
        cv2.hconcat((frame, red)),
        cv2.hconcat((green, blue))
    ))

    cv2.imshow('frame', final)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You can `resize` the frame once you read it ;D

Comment: I don't know how I missed that lol, Thanks @Miki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the cap.set and the color shapes to after the read location fixes my problem.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, int(640 *.5))
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, int(480 *.5))
    red = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')
    green = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')
    blue = np.zeros(frame.shape, 'uint8')
    b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)

    red[..., 0], red[..., 1], red[..., 2] = r, r, r
    green[..., 0], green[..., 1], green[..., 2] = g, g, g
    blue[..., 0], blue[..., 1], blue[..., 2] = b, b, b

    final = cv2.vconcat((
        cv2.hconcat((frame, red)),
        cv2.hconcat((green, blue))
    ))

    cv2.imshow('frame', final)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```